# Can't create MKCoordinateRegion object

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two views. First one, have a map, which displays flag of some countries. The second one should display map, and center it according to the user choose.

In first view, inside of body, I have NavigationLink:

```
NavigationLink {
 CountriesBordersPins(countries: countries, coords:country.coordinates)
 } label: {
    ...
}
```

In second View, I have two variables

```
let countries: [Country]
@State var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

From the coords variable, I've wanted to create an `MKCoordinateRegion` object:

```
   @State var visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = {
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)
    return MKCoordinateRegion(center: coords, span: span)
}()
```

but I can't refer to passed `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object. How I can make this thing work?

Comment: It seems like `Region` depends on the input parameter `coords`, so how about making it such as computed property? And I think you should change the @State to @Binding because the second view doesn't own the `coords`, it's passed from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try something simple, like declare:

```
  @State var visibleRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
```

and in your view body add

```
 .onAppear {
     visibleRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coords, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`coords` should not be a `@State`.

If the second view does not change `coords` (will not assign to it, will not make a `Binding` out of it etc), `coords` should just be a `let` constant, and you can initialise `coords`, along with `visibleRegion`, in an initialiser.

```
let countries: [Country]
let coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D
let visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion

init(countries: [Country], coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.countries = countries
    self.coords = coords
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)
    self.visibleRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coords, span: span)
}
```

If the second view needs to change `coords`, it should be a `Binding`.

```
@Binding var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

```
// pass a binding to coords - you should be able to get a binding from country.coordinates
// if this is a in ForEach(countries) { country in ... }
// use ForEach($countries) { $country in ... } instead
CountriesBordersPins(countries: countries, coords: $country.coordinates)
```

Then change `visibleRegion` to a computed property:

```
var visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion {
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)
    return MKCoordinateRegion(center: coords, span: span)
}
```